# How to add a little square into input for preview a color with colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I want to add a little square into my input text where I can change color according to the input value like this photo:

[image]

I have to use [bootstrap colorpicker](https://itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/)

at this moment I have this in my code:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="theme-color"
           class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">{{__('template.edit.site_identity.description')}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div id="demo">
               <input type="text"
                    id="theme-color"
                    class="form-control @error('theme-color') is-invalid @enderror"
                    name="theme-color"
                    value="#FFFFFF">
               @error('theme-color')
               <span class="input-group-append">
                      <span
                      class="input-group-text colorpicker-input-addon"><i></i></span>
               </span>
               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
                 @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#theme-color').colorpicker();
</script>
```

how can I add the little square and change the color according to the value from the "theme-color" input?

Comment: You can just use: `<input type="color">`. No need for a library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could style a parent element that is wrapping an input type of color using CSS. Then use JS to change the text inputs value to the **color-theme** on change using an event listener.

***Note on Styling:*** depending on the height of your input, you can style the trailing element, `<span>` *tag in my example*, to look exactly like the color picker in your picture snipit. You may need to play around with the styles for these elements. I added some flex display to easily center elements in their parents as well.

```js
let color = document.querySelector('.colorPick')
let themeColor = document.querySelector('#theme-color')

const setColor = (colorSel, textSel) => {
  // change the value to the default color
  themeColor.value = color.value
  // event listener to change the text input value when the pickers value changes
  color.addEventListener('change', () => {
    return themeColor.value = color.value
  })
}

setColor(color, themeColor)
```

```css
#demo {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
}

#theme-color {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

#theme-color:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.picker {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 22px;
  width: 32px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-left: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.colorPick {
  height: 16px;
  width: 31px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="theme-color" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold"></label>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div id="demo">
      <!--// remove readonly attribute if you want users to be able to type in the color themselves //-->
      <input type="text" id="theme-color" class="form-control @error('theme-color') is-invalid @enderror" name="theme-color" value="#FFFFFF" readonly>
      <span class="picker"><input class="colorPick" type="color"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input type color and the oninput JavaScript event. This means whenever the color is changed or inputted, something will be executed. Let's do this:

```js
function update() {
  var input_color = document.getElementById('yourColorPicker').value;
  document.getElementById('text_output').value = input_color;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  document.getElementById('output').style.backgroundColor = input_color;
}
```

```css
#output {
  display:block;
  height: 15% !important;
  width: 15% !important;
}

input[type=text] {
  font-family:monospace;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <span>Select the color:</span>
  <input type="color" id="yourColorPicker" oninput="update();" />
  <div id="output">Not set! Click the color picker to continue.</div>
  <p>Your hex color code:</p>
  <input type="text" id="text_output" value="Pick a color, and I promise there'll be some hex code here." />
</body>

</html>
```

This program updates a text input field and a div with the selected colors. No external libraries required.